# Multiple queries on one transaction. C# winforms with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm learning how to use SQLite, and I'm stuck on this problem for more than a week and I didn't find an answer on my web search.

The problem is that I need to register a bill with it's corresponding lines, and update some information of the bought products, all in the same transaction if some query fails.

When I try to register something, I obtain the **"Database is locked"** exception, but what I found strange is that I kept the program running while I was creating this question and when I saw it again I found that the "continue" button was available, and then the program finally worked.

So I would like to know what I must improve to not have that exception.

**Ah, it's a Winforms application, and only one person will use it, so it will not have concurrency problems (or I think so).**

First, this is the **connectionString** (if I need to add something to it):
*"Data Source=D:\De disco c\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Racion\Racion\bin\Racion.db;Version=3;"*

On the Mapper of the bill's class I have this method:

```
public static void registrarFactura(Factura f)
{

    SQLiteConnection conn = null;
    SQLiteTransaction trn = null;

    try
    {

        var parametros = new List<SQLiteParameter>();
        var cant = new SQLiteParameter();
        cant.ParameterName = "@Cliente";
        cant.Value = f.cliente;
        parametros.Add(cant);

        cant = new SQLiteParameter();
        cant.ParameterName = "@Fecha";
        cant.Value = DateTime.Now;

        parametros.Add(cant);
        //Here is one query. I need to know the bill's ID to register the lines and make the update.
        String consulta = "Insert into Factura(Cliente, Fecha)  VALUES (@Cliente, @Fecha); SELECT last_insert_rowid();";


        //Open the connection
        conn = ObtenerConection();


        //begin transaction
        using (trn = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //Here I register the bill and obtain it's id
            int codigo = Convert.ToInt32(Mapper.ejecutaScalar(consulta, CommandType.Text, parametros, conn, trn));

            //Now I must register the lines of the bill

             String consulta2 = "";

            foreach (Linea l in f.lineas)
            {
                parametros = new List<SQLiteParameter>();
                cant = new SQLiteParameter();
                cant.ParameterName = "@NLinea";
                cant.Value = l.numeroLinea;
                parametros.Add(cant);

                cant = new SQLiteParameter();
                cant.ParameterName = "@Cantidad";
                cant.Value = l.cantidad;
                parametros.Add(cant);

                cant = new SQLiteParameter();
                cant.ParameterName = "@CodigoProd";
                cant.Value = l.producto.Codigo;
                parametros.Add(cant);

                cant = new SQLiteParameter();
                cant.ParameterName = "@PTotal";
                cant.Value = l.PrecioTotal;
                parametros.Add(cant);

                cant = new SQLiteParameter();
                cant.ParameterName = "@Codigo";
                cant.Value = codigo;
                parametros.Add(cant);

                //The query to insert the actual line of the foreach
                consulta = "Insert into Linea(IdFactura, IdLinea, IdProducto, Cantidad, Total) VALUES (" + codigo + ", @NLinea, @CodigoProd, @Cantidad, @PTotal)";

                Mapper.EjecutaNonQuery(consulta, CommandType.Text, parametros, conn, null);

                //Update the stock of the product
                if (f.cliente == "")
                {
                    consulta2 = "Update Producto Set Cantidad=Cantidad+@Cantidad Where IdProducto=@CodigoProd;";
                }
                else
                {
                    consulta2 = "Update Producto Set Cantidad=Cantidad-@Cantidad Where IdProducto=@CodigoProd;";
                }

                Mapper.EjecutaNonQuery(consulta2, CommandType.Text, parametros, conn, null);


            }

            //The transaction concludes
            trn.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //If there is a problem
        trn.Rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close the connection
        CerrarConexion(conn);
    }

}
```

And on the mapper class, I have these 2 methods that are used  in the previous one:

```
public static object ejecutaScalar(string sentencia, CommandType tipoComando, List<SQLiteParameter> parametros, SQLiteConnection con, SQLiteTransaction trn)
{
    object retorno;
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = sentencia;
        cmd.CommandType = tipoComando;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
        if (trn != null)
            cmd.Transaction = trn;
        retorno = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    }

    return retorno;
}

public static int EjecutaNonQuery(string sentencia, CommandType tipoComando, List<SQLiteParameter> parametros, SQLiteConnection con, SQLiteTransaction trn)
{
    int afectadas = -1;

    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = sentencia;
        cmd.CommandType = tipoComando;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parametros.ToArray());
        if (trn != null)
            cmd.Transaction = trn;
        afectadas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    return afectadas;
}
```

Thanks, and sorry if I couldn't explain me better, English is not my native language and I have some difficulties with it :P

Comment: Try disposing of the SQLiteCommand `cmd.Dispose()`

Comment: @crimson589 No need, it's in a using block

Comment: It is not an answer for your question, but it will solve this and many other problems: use an ORM. for example [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I used the Dispose in other methods, and it worked, but as @Tamás Szabó said, it was not necessary on the methods above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "database is locked" means that there is some *other* connection that has an active transaction.

To ensure that transactions do not stay active, check that *all* SQL command and transaction objects are used only with `using` blocks, or otherwise cleaned up. Furthermore, the entire program should use only a single connection object (unless it has multiple threads); you should not re-open it every time (which just makes everything slower because the page cache gets lost).

Comment: Thank you!. This solution was useful for me. I checked all other methods I have, and they were a lot with that kind of problem you said.