# C# Sqlite insert many with transaction throws error

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions

I have this method defined:

```
public void InsertRecords(List<string> records, Device device)
        {
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var insRecStmt =
                        new SQLiteCommand(
                            "INSERT INTO records(content) VALUES(@content);", conn);
                    var fooStmt = new SQLiteCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO foo(rec_id, bar) VALUES (@rec_id, @bar);",
                        conn);
                    insRecStmt.Transaction = transaction;
                    fooStmt.Transaction = transaction;
                    fooStmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bar", device.Id);
                    foreach (var record in records)
                    {
                        insRecStmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", record.ToString());
                        insRecStmt.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        var rowID = conn.LastInsertRowId;
                        fooStmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rec_id", rowID);
                        fooStmt.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
```

but for some reason, I keep getting this exception:

```
Unhandled exception. code = Busy (5), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007AF): database is locked
database is locked
```

I do not have any other connections left open or unhandled.
Any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: On which line do you get that exception? It looks like you need `insRecStmt.Parameters.Clear(); fooStmt.Parameters.Clear();` at the end of the loop. Or you can create the parameters once, and change them in the loop, rather than adding. It's also probably easier to just do this as one batch with two inserts

Comment: Added clears, no luck, how do I do in one batch 2 inserts? I need to get id of first insert and supply it to another insert.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you remove all the transaction related  code?

Comment: Separate the 2 queries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133933/multiple-queries-on-one-transaction-c-sharp-winforms-with-sqlite & https://stackoverflow.com/a/6749677/14171304

Comment: The code as shown succeeds for me (100,000 inserts per transaction, SQLite 1.0.115.5).  Compare your real code to that shown in the question and adjust if needed.  Otherwise there are external factors at play that we can't see here.